# SearcherManager and MultiReader in Lucene

Tags: lucene

I am using Lucene and I have a MultiReader from a few directory readers like:

```
MutiReader myMultiReader = new Multireader(directoryReader1, directoryReader2,...)
```

I want to use SearcherManager from it since there will be changes in the index from time to time. How can I do this? SeacherManager only accepts a single DirectoryReader or IndexWriter as parameters in the constructor

https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/SearcherManager.html

I don't understand how I could combine both MultiReader and SearcherManager.

By the way, I have already checked this links which don't really answer this particular issue:
http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/09/lucenes-searchermanager-simplifies.html
http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/SearcherManager-vs-MultiReader-td4068411.html

Comment: I know this question is very old but were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: This was a long time ago.... No, I never got an answer.